# How to replace image tag in a compose.yml file for one container

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I have compose.yml file where I have multiple containers with common image-tag variable and am passing the value of variable from Jenkins .
Image-tag/version is same for all applications.
Incase if for particular container if I want to use old container version and rest containers will have same new version.
How do I do it